# How would i group by a specific row in a pandas dataframe and run a code for each group before moving onto the next group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I am trying to use an excel sheet and then group them by their Record ID and run a specific code for that Record ID, and then move onto the next Record ID and run the same code.

In the example image I attached I have a column called Record ID that groups up the rows based on the Quantity Difference.

*** Believe there is problems uploading Image so ill write the example in a table***

**TABLE**

```
RecordID | securityAmount | Quantity Difference
25         7595.255          84585.651
25         7620.256          84585.651
24         22.46             75.049
24          52.589           75.049
```

The goal of this project is to run a code to tell me if any sort of combination from the securityAmount column equals to the Quantity Difference

The code used to run this is:

```
import itertools

quantityDifference = 9751.511
securityAmount = [3584.091,
22.543,
17941.162,
16838.976,
9746.422,
21123.342
]
result = [seq for i in range (len(numbers), 0, -1) for seq in itertools.combinations(securityAmount, i) if round(sum(seq),3) == quantityDifference]
print(result)
```

This code works how I intended if I hardcode the numbers but I obviously want it to run dynamically so I want to replace the inputs with what is found on the excel sheet.

This is where I am currently at with my code due to my limited knowledge in Pandas:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel(r'\\my\file\.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['securityAmount', 'Quantity Difference', 'RecordID'])
```

So far it is set up to what I want and now I need help in doing the following logic (See photo for reference as I run through the logic)

I want to run the code I listed above for each group based on the RecordID

Also note, for each group I only need one of the quantity difference as they will be the exact same for each group, but the security amount is what differs

As an example, the first sequence it should perform is based on recordID 25 and the goal is to see if any combination of numbers will equal to the quantity difference (The amount of numbers in the securityAmount can vary. It could be 10 numbers, two numbers etc.. but the above code will produce this)

In RecordID 25 there are no possible combinations so the result would be [] and I want to see that
For RecordID 24 the two numbers equal to the quantity difference so the output returns as [22.46,52.589]
There is not any shown in the pciture here but if there are 10 numbers and three are the combinations it will return [x,y,z]

Can someone help in guiding me towards how I can make my code do this code for every single group and once done move onto the next group until it goes through the entire sheet?

Thank you!

Expected Outcome:

```
securityAmount | Quantity Difference | RecordID | Combinations
50                  120                   1         [50,30,40]
27                   120                   1        [50,30,40] 
30                   120                   1        [50,30,40]
40                   120                   1        [50,30,40]
98                    50                   2        []
300                   50                   2        []
```

Comment: Post sample data like you did. Pictures of code and data won't go over well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a better way to do this but i hope this helps you:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({"RecordID": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2], "securityAmount": [50, 27, 30, 40, 98, 300],"Quantity Difference": [120, 120, 120, 120, 50, 50]})
combinations = []
for i in data.RecordID:
  temp = data.loc[data["RecordID"] == i]
  quantityDifference = list(temp["Quantity Difference"])[0]
  securityAmount = list(temp["securityAmount"])
  result = [seq for i in range (len(securityAmount), 0, -1) for seq in itertools.combinations(securityAmount, i) if round(sum(seq),3) == quantityDifference]
  combinations.append(result)
  print(result)
data["Combinations"] = combinations
print(data)
```

Whitout using headers in the code:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({"RecordID": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2], "securityAmount": [50, 27, 30, 40, 98, 300],"Quantity Difference": [120, 120, 120, 120, 50, 50]})
combinations = []
for i in data[list(data.columns)[0]]:
  temp = data.loc[data[list(data.columns)[0]] == i]
  quantityDifference = list(temp[list(data.columns)[2]])[0]
  securityAmount = list(temp[list(data.columns)[1]])
  result = [seq for i in range (len(securityAmount), 0, -1) for seq in itertools.combinations(securityAmount, i) if round(sum(seq),3) == quantityDifference]
  combinations.append(result)
  print(result)
data["Combinations"] = combinations
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[(50, 30, 40)]
[(50, 30, 40)]
[(50, 30, 40)]
[(50, 30, 40)]
[]
[]
   RecordID  securityAmount  Quantity Difference    Combinations
0         1              50                  120  [(50, 30, 40)]
1         1              27                  120  [(50, 30, 40)]
2         1              30                  120  [(50, 30, 40)]
3         1              40                  120  [(50, 30, 40)]
4         2              98                   50              []
5         2             300                   50              []
```

Comment: This is super helpful actually. One thing that might fully flesh it out, instead of of putting in the RecordID, securityamount and quantity difference in manually as data, is there a way to dynamically have it change itself since the files every day will have different data?

Comment: If the data will always be in the same column (Like IDs to search in the first, the numbers to search posible combinations in the second one, and the result in the third one), then yes, i will edit my answer and add that.